# jaxb2 SAXParseException: Invalid content was found

Tags: xml, marshalling, sax, jaxb2, bipro

i am working on marshalling java objects to xml using spring.oxm and jaxb2 with SAX Parser.

I am running into a problem with my marshaller throwing an org.xml.sax.SAXParseException stating that there is:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'ns59:ArtID'. One of
>   {[...],http://www.bipro.net/namespace/gevo":ArtID, [...]} is expected.

In my org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.graph everything seems to be ok, at least for my understanding. 
The graph shows these variables in debug mode:
[image]
This is the jaxax.xml.transform.result.writer before breaking off with the error and leaving the output string like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns43:getShipmentResponse 
xmlns="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/basis" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/nachrichten" 
xmlns:ns3="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/abrechnung" 
xmlns:ns4="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/allgemein" 
xmlns:ns5="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/schaden-leistung" 
xmlns:ns6="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/partner" 
xmlns:ns7="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/sachen" 
xmlns:ns8="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/produktmodell/rechtsschutz" 
xmlns:ns9="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/produktmodell" 
xmlns:ns10="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/produktmodell" 
xmlns:ns11="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kapitalanlage/basis" 
xmlns:ns12="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/produktmodell/komposit" 
xmlns:ns13="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kapitalanlage/transaktion" 
xmlns:ns14="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/provision" 
xmlns:ns15="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/beteiligungsverhaeltnis" 
xmlns:ns16="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kapitalanlage" 
xmlns:ns17="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/produktmodell/kraftfahrt" 
xmlns:ns18="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/fragen" 
xmlns:ns19="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/produktmodell/kranken" 
xmlns:ns20="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/vertrag" 
xmlns:ns21="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/foerderung" 
xmlns:ns22="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/produktmodell/leben" 
xmlns:ns23="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/unfall" 
xmlns:ns24="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/sepa" 
xmlns:ns25="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/haftpflicht" 
xmlns:ns26="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/schaden-objekte" 
xmlns:ns27="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/schaden-details" 
xmlns:ns28="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/sach" 
xmlns:ns29="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/fahrzeug"
xmlns:ns30="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/gevo" 
xmlns:ns32="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/evb" 
xmlns:ns33="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/foerderdaten" 
xmlns:ns34="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/partner" 
xmlns:ns35="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/schaden" 
xmlns:ns36="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/vertrag" 
xmlns:ns37="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/versicherung/vertrag/komposit" 
xmlns:ns38="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/versicherung/vertrag/kraftfahrt" 
xmlns:ns39="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/versicherung/vertrag/kranken" 
xmlns:ns40="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/prozesse/versicherung/vertrag/leben" 
xmlns:ns41="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/versicherung/tarifierung" 
xmlns:ns42="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/tools/iban" 
xmlns:ns43="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer" 
xmlns:ns44="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/abrechnung" 
xmlns:ns45="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/gevo" 
xmlns:ns46="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/inkassostoerfall" 
xmlns:ns47="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/schaden-leistung" 
xmlns:ns48="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/schadenrueckfrage" 
xmlns:ns49="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/sepa" 
xmlns:ns50="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/vertrag" 
xmlns:ns51="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/beruf" 
xmlns:ns52="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/betriebsart" 
xmlns:ns53="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/fahrzeug" 
xmlns:ns54="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/partner" 
xmlns:ns55="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/schaden" 
xmlns:ns56="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/unternehmen" 
xmlns:ns57="http://www.bipro.net/namespace/kontext/vertrag" 
xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">             <ns43:Response>
            <ns2:BiPROVersion>2.6.1.0.0</ns2:BiPROVersion>
            <ns2:Status>
                <ns2:ProzessID>1530635989611</ns2:ProzessID>
                <ns2:Zeitstempel>2018-07-03T18:41:12</ns2:Zeitstempel>
                <ns2:StatusID>OK</ns2:StatusID>
                <ns2:Schwebe>false</ns2:Schwebe>
                <ns2:Meldung>
                    <ns2:ArtID>Hinweis</ns2:ArtID>
                    <ns2:MeldungID>04000</ns2:MeldungID>
                </ns2:Meldung>
            </ns2:Status>
            <ns43:Lieferung>
                <ns43:ID>1530636072667</ns43:ID>
                <ns43:Einstellzeitpunkt>2016-12-05T00:00:00</ns43:Einstellzeitpunkt>
                <ns43:Kategorie>120000000</ns43:Kategorie>
                <ns43:VerfuegbarBis>2019-12-05</ns43:VerfuegbarBis>
                <ns43:Transfer xsi:type="ns45:CT_GeVoTransfer" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Has anyone an idea and can point me to the right direction?

Lexicore asked for 2 things.
1. the complete XSD, which you can take from my open github repo at https://github.com/JoBieker/soap-bipro/tree/master/securess-bipro/src/main/resources/xsd. 
2. the complete xml, which i have not, as i wanted to create it. but if i would have been successful something like this should have come out.  this is a nother gevo-transfer case, but the structure should be the same. You can download here:  https://github.com/JoBieker/soap-bipro/blob/master/securess-bipro/src/main/resources/target-xml.xml

Finally lexicores questions taught me that i totally forgot to mention that i wanted to marshall a xml. So here it is and there is the code on my public github repo: https://github.com/JoBieker/soap-bipro
And here is the complete exception as provided by the console:

> 2018-07-04 22:19:46.407
>   ERROR 12986 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'securessBiproApplication': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'marshaller'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'createJaxb2Marshaller' defined in class path
>   resource [de/securess/bipro/config/Jaxb2Config.class]: Unexpected
>   exception during bean creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'context.path' in value "${context.path}"     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
>   de.securess.bipro.SecuressBiproApplication.main(SecuressBiproApplication.java:43)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'createJaxb2Marshaller' defined in class path
>   resource [de/securess/bipro/config/Jaxb2Config.class]: Unexpected
>   exception during bean creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'context.path' in value "${context.path}"     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   ... 18 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   resolve placeholder 'context.path' in value "${context.path}"     at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:839)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   ... 26 common frames
>   omitted

Best regards, jcb

Comment: Please post your complete XML and relevant XSD parts.

Comment: Ah, you're marshalling. The please post the relevant code. How do you construct your object and how do you marshall. Especially the relevant `ArtID` part. And the complete exception details.

Comment: Hi Lexicore, i added the requested information. The just go to the github repo on https://github.com/JoBieker/soap-bipro where you can get the complete maven project to install into your ide. Looking forward hearing from you. JCB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

The problem was not in marshalling, but in the validation.

You have configured JAXB to validate the marshalled XML agains the specified schemas:

```
    marshaller.setSchemas(
            new ClassPathResource("/xsd/bipro-nachrichten-2.6.0.xsd"),
            new ClassPathResource("/xsd/bipro-transfer-2.6.0.xsd"),
            new ClassPathResource("/xsd/bipro-transfer-gevo-2.6.0.xsd"),
            new ClassPathResource("/xsd/bipro-gevo-2.6.0.xsd"),
            new ClassPathResource("/xsd/bipro-prozesse-vertrag-2.6.0.xsd"),
            new ClassPathResource("/xsd/bipro-basis-2.6.0.xsd")
            );
```

The problem appears in the `ArtID` element of the `CT_Geschaeftsvorgang` type. This is how you set this element in your Java code:

```
    JAXBElement<String> value = new JAXBElement<String>(
            new QName("http://wwww.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/gevo","ArtID"), String.class, "value"
            );
    value.setValue("120000000");
    CTGeschaeftsvorgang ctVertragsauskunft = new CTVertragsauskunft();
    ctVertragsauskunft.setArtID(value);
```

Note the namespace URI: `http://wwww.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/gevo`, with four `w`s and `transfer` before `gevo`.

Now if you carefully check your schema `bipro-gevo-2.6.0.xsd` you will see that it has a different namespace:

The correct namespace is `http://www.bipro.net/namespace/gevo`.

[Changing](https://github.com/JoBieker/soap-bipro/pull/2/commits/9b5b51535dfac08725aad3d161a53d8a3ac12601) `http://wwww.bipro.net/namespace/transfer/gevo` to `http://www.bipro.net/namespace/gevo` in your Java code fixes the problem.